# Ground Overlay in Google map?

Tags: google-maps

I'd like upload the KML file which including the PNG file on the Google Map.
The process was done normally. But I could not see the PNG data on the Google map.
Related  files are as follows;

1) KML source file with text format;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<GroundOverlay><name>ER001_Polda Balicpapan.png</name><color>88ffffff</color><Icon>
<href>ER001_Polda Balicpapan.png</href>
<viewBoundScale>0.75</viewBoundScale></Icon><LatLonBox>
<north>-.690568</north>
<south>-1.770432</south>
<east> 117.8462</east>
<west> 115.925</west>
</LatLonBox></GroundOverlay></kml>`
```

2) Message on the Google map

> It can not display a row of data(ER001.PNG)

Please let me know that how can I display this Ground Overlay on the Google Map?

Answer (score 0):

See the example in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut#ground_overlays)

Put the image somewhere publicly available and use the fully qualified URL.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Folder>
    <name>Ground Overlays</name>
    <description>Examples of ground overlays</description>
    <GroundOverlay>
      <name>Large-scale overlay on terrain</name>
      <description>Overlay shows Mount Etna erupting 
          on July 13th, 2001.</description>
      <Icon>
        <href>https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/images/etna.jpg</href>
      </Icon>
      <LatLonBox>
        <north>37.91904192681665</north>
        <south>37.46543388598137</south>
        <east>15.35832653742206</east>
        <west>14.60128369746704</west>
        <rotation>-0.1556640799496235</rotation>
      </LatLonBox>
    </GroundOverlay>
  </Folder>
</kml>
```

another option would be to create a [KMZ file](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmzarchives) that includes the image in the correct relative path.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked only in the Google Earth Pro. But not worked on the  google.com/maps. How can I do?

Comment: [example using geoxml3](http://geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?lat=37.464151&lng=15.386503&zoom=9&type=m&filename=KML_Samples.xml)